# Effect of recent casts on opponents playstyle

Tags: starcraft-2

I've noticed a correlation between my opponents play-style and the set of casts (VODs) recently released.  It seems the more popular the caster, the more likely I'm going to face whatever strategy they're show-casing or recommending.  A good example of this is when Day9 released a 'Refining a build order' cast that showed how to do 1 reaper FE - it seems like I faced this build against at least 50% of my Terran opponents for the week or so after it was released.

**I'm wondering first if any of you have also noticed this coorelation, and second whether anyone wants to prove or disprove it.**

I know that most people are attracted to this site because they are both programmers and Starcraft players, and I believe all the necessary data is available, we can see what builds people are using (both from battle.net and the advanced replay sites), and we know what the casters are sticking out there.

I realize this information wouldn't be useful to you Master leaguers' as most of you aren't getting your builds from the casting sites, but for those of us playing Bronze-Plat I'm wondering if we could improve our results by planning our builds to counter what is being seen in recent casts.

Thanks!

Comment: This could just be a case of "I'm paying attention to it, so I notice it more"

Comment: @Resorath - that's called memory bias.

Comment: @Resorath/@Raven Agreed, that's why I'm asking here.  Or maybe I'm trying to prove correlation=causation, you decide :)

Comment: I don't have the hard data, but there is definitely at least some correlation, after marineking's rise to fame (at the time under the name of Boxer), the ladder was filled with mass marine-ing players. After Losira vs Alicia, the so-called Losira build has risen to prominence as well. Also, most master league players do get their builds from the pros.

Comment: @Joe Behymer I'm not sure that this is a question. More like a poll or forum topic. What is your question?

Comment: @Meta - I'm wondering if we could improve our results by planning our builds to counter what is being seen in recent casts.  This root question makes me ask (and bold in the OP) this: I'm wondering first if any of you have also noticed this coorelation, and second whether anyone wants to prove or disprove it.

Comment: @Joe yes.  Though less prevalent on the NA server, builds which get a lot of attention start to pop up a lot more (eg. Spanishiwa); practicing counter builds to these "popular" builds is a wise decision.  If you want to know more please visit [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) sometime and ping me there.

Comment: I'm going to be more specific and call this Availability Heuristics

Comment: @tzenes if you want to move that to answer I'll accept it.  I've found related discussion on teamliquid, although no-one has seemed to want to write the code to prove it (which I understand, otherwise I'd write it myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice the correlation, but In my own experience, I tried in practice some features seen from casters :)

Don't think you can build your strategy based on recent casts. I see few reasons for that:

1. Not everybody can get benefits of PRO-gamers strategies;
2. You can't know in advance which EXACTLY strategy will be used against you.

Scout 1st, you will see opponents build... If you believe something and do counter to what you believe, that will much worst than doing more generic strategy.

Answer (score 1):

@OP's request:

Though less prevalent on the NA server (in comparison to KR), builds which get a lot of attention start to pop up a lot more (eg. Spanishiwa); practicing counter builds to these "popular" builds is a wise decision.

I have no hard data to back this up, but I have found it to be overwhelmingly true.